# Why doesn't C# have a non-virtual calling convention?

Tags: c#, language-design

Inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378010/how-to-invoke-non-virtually-the-original-implementation-of-a-virtual-method):

Why doesn't C# have a keyword for non-virtual calling convention?

EDIT: I mean "why is there no keyword for non-virtual IL calls, given that the C# compiler always uses IL virtual calls by default"?

Comment: Ah, one of the pitfalls of mainstream OOP languages (even C++, which allows this)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might explain it: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt)

Shortly: `call` instruction can accept `null` as `this` pointer (as it is in C++). This is errorsome and C# team decided to use `callvirt` wherever it is possible so that calls on `null` pointers throw `NullReferenceException`

Comment: I think this addresses another issue than the one the OP asks about.

Comment: @0xA3 @Hans Passant i had a feeling that question was stated incorrectly by author. look at edit, i guessed right

Comment: Too bad, would have been a great question.

Comment: The authors of C# might not have liked the idea of being able to pass a null "this" pointer, but there are some cases where it could have improved legibility [e.g. being able to say SomeString.IsNullOrEmpty instead of String.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeString)].

Comment: @supercat it would improve few cases and mess up a lot of other.

Comment: @Andrey: My preference would be to allow a means by which extension methods that operated on objects of a particular class could be declared within that class and obey the scoping rules of that class.  Incidentally, if I had my druthers, struct members other than constructors would be forbidden from mutating "this", but structs could declare extension methods which took their "this" parameter by reference.  Such a change would break existing .net code, of course, but one could deprecate changes to "this" to allow code to migrate toward the safer syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [why c# implements methods as non-virtual by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814934/why-c-implements-methods-as-non-virtual-by-default)

To quote Anders Hejlsberg

> There are several reasons. One is
> performance. We can observe that as
> people write code in Java, they forget
> to mark their methods final.
> Therefore, those methods are virtual.
> Because they're virtual, they don't
> perform as well. There's just
> performance overhead associated with
> being a virtual method. That's one
> issue.
>
> A more important issue is versioning.
> There are two schools of thought about
> virtual methods. The academic school
> of thought says, "Everything should be
> virtual, because I might want to
> override it someday." The pragmatic
> school of thought, which comes from
> building real applications that run in
> the real world, says, "We've got to be
> real careful about what we make
> virtual."
>
> When we make something virtual in a
> platform, we're making an awful lot of
> promises about how it evolves in the
> future. For a non-virtual method, we
> promise that when you call this
> method, x and y will happen. When we
> publish a virtual method in an API, we
> not only promise that when you call
> this method, x and y will happen. We
> also promise that when you override
> this method, we will call it in this
> particular sequence with regard to
> these other ones and the state will be
> in this and that invariant.
>
> Every time you say virtual in an API,
> you are creating a call back hook. As
> an OS or API framework designer,
> you've got to be real careful about
> that. You don't want users overriding
> and hooking at any arbitrary point in
> an API, because you cannot necessarily
> make those promises. And people may
> not fully understand the promises they
> are making when they make something
> virtual.

Source: http://www.artima.com/intv/nonvirtual.html

Comment: This is somewhat off-topic. The question is why can't we call a method through a non-virtual IL call. Calls to non-virtual methods in C# still use an IL virtual call instruction, as other have said. I wonder if people just vote the longest post up, or they actually read them.

Comment: @Mau, I wouldnt call it off-topic. This answers the question "Why doesn’t C# have a non-virtual calling convention?" and thats the title of the question, well atleast before the edit.