# Using variance to convert a parent class (ObservableCollection) to a child

Tags: c#, observablecollection, variance

Until I tried to do this, I assumed that I knew how this worked; however, the following code throws an exception.  Because `TestOC` is a child of `ObservableCollection`, I thought I could do this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class TestOC : ObservableCollection<MyClass>
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObservableCollection<MyClass> test = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
        test.Add(new MyClass());

        TestOC test2 = (TestOC)test;
    }
}
```

The error thrown is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[ConsoleApplication17.MyClass]' to type 'ConsoleApplication17.TestOC'.

How can I get the `ObservableCollection` to assign to my child class here?

Comment: Why do you want to cast a parent class to its subclass?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534253/c-sharp-converting-base-class-to-child-class

Comment: You can't cast an arbitrary `Animal` to a `Dog`.  You can create a _new_ `Dog` with the same properties as the `Animal` but you can't cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` to `TestOC`.

Because it is derived. Meaning `TestOC` extends `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`. So if you want to cast an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` to `TestOC`, it is missing the functionality that `TestOC` adds. *(even when the subclass doesn't have anything extra)*

**But** you could cast a `TestOC` to an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`. Because `TestOC` does implement all what an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` implements.

---

**This doesn't work**:

```
TestOC test2 = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
```

---

**This does work**:

```
ObservableCollection<MyClass> test2 = new TestOC();
```

---

> How can I get the ObservableCollection to assign to my child class here?

You cannot, but there are some options:

1 - Instead of creating a `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`, you should construct a `TestOC`.  *(new TestOC())*

2 -  If you don't want to write `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` but a shorter version, you could use **aliases**, but this doesn't add any functionality. It's only syntactic sugar. This way you could `new` a TestOC but behind it is a `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` so fully assignable.

```
using TestOC = System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MyClass>;
```