# How to convert parent collection object to child collection object without looping in C#?

Tags: c#

I have following object structure where B is derived from A and I am getting input as `List<A>` with lots of records. I want to convert that`List<A>` to `List<B>` with easy steps (without looping). What is the best way to achieve the same.

Note: I don't want to use AutoMapper.

```
    public class A
    {
        public A() { }
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public B()
            : base()
        {
        }
        private string _name;
        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = string.Concat("Hello ", base.Name);
            }
        }

        public string Id
        {
            get { return "101"; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of interest, what is the purpose of this?

Comment: If `List<A>` actually contains objects of only type `B`, then you can just use LINQ Cast `List<B> listB = listA.Cast<B>().ToList()`.

Comment: I already tried that its giving - Unable to cast object of type 'A' to type 'B'. exception.

Comment: Try creating the list of B and adding the range of listA.Cast<B>().

Comment: Tried your suggestion - var listA = new List<A> { new A { Name = "John" }, new A { Name = "Peter" }, new A { Name = "Julia" } };

List<B> listB = new List<B>().AddRange(listA); Not working

Comment: @SumitDeshpande What is the reason you want to create list of `Base Class` and than get list of `Derived Class`?

Comment: I am getting List of Base class as Input and I want to build my derived class by massaging few Base class properties. E.g. Name property, suppose if Base has Name=”John” then in B class I want “Hello John” that’s the difference.

Comment: You can cast (B)ear as (A)nimal, but not (A)nimal as (B)ear, because an animal is not necessarily a bear. You need to do `List<A> ListA = new List<B>();` then you can properly cast `ListA` to `List<B>`. Otherwise, you need to convert the `A` into `B` explicitly.

Comment: @kurakura88 he can't explicitly cast `A` to `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by declaring constructor for class B from class A 
in this way:

```
public B(A a):base()
{
    this._name = a.Name;
}
```

And than do this:

```
var listA = new List<A> { new A { Name = "John" }, new A { Name = "Peter" }, new A { Name = "Julia" } }; 
List<B> listB = listA.Select(x=> new B(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: I actually don't want to use loop but I think your solution is correct we have to run linq query to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments this is the output, though I still don't really understand the point.

```
        List<A> thisIsA = new List<A>();

        thisIsA.Add(new B());

        List<B> thisIsB = new List<B>();
        thisIsB.AddRange(thisIsA.Cast<B>());
```

Comment: this will throw Exception if in `thisIsA` exists instance of `class A`

Comment: It will which is why I say I don't full understand the point but based on the OP thisIsA in this context will never hold an instance of class A

Comment: look at his example in the comments thisIsA has only instances of A

Comment: I don't know if this post would be of any help https://stackoverflow.com/a/16534314/1521076