# Getting two bits of data into one c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have got the data from a text file to fill in the text boxes with the data. However I am trying to get an employees salary from another class into the text box and I am struggling to do so. My first class is the employee class with this code:

```
public class Employee
{
    string _firstName;
    string _lastName;
    string _address;
    string _postCode;
    string _phoneNumber;
    DateTime _dateOfBirth;

    public Employee()
    {
    }

    public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, string address, string postCode, string phoneNumber, DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
        _address = address;
        _postCode = postCode;
        _phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        _dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public string firstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
        }
    }

    public string lastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
        }
    }

    public string address
    {
        get
        {
            return _address;
        }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
        }
    }

    public string postCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _postCode;
        }
        set
        {
            _postCode = value;
        }
    }

    public string phoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _phoneNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime dateOfBirth
    {
        get
        {
            return _dateOfBirth;
        }
        set
        {
            _dateOfBirth = value;
        }
    }
```

followed by the salaried class with this code:

```
 public class SalariedEmployee : Employee
 {
    decimal _salary;

    public SalariedEmployee(string firstName, string lastName, string 
   address, string postCode, string phoneNumber, DateTime dateOfBirth, 
 decimal salary) : base(firstName, lastName, address, postCode, phoneNumber, 
 dateOfBirth)
    {
        _salary = salary;
    }

    public decimal salary
    {
        get
        {
            return _salary;
        }
        set
        {
            _salary = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

this then goes onto the load method which is as follows:

```
public bool Load(string employeesFile)    
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("employees.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //Splitting the data using |
            string[] temp = line.Split('|');

            int year = Convert.ToInt32(temp[5]);
            int month = Convert.ToInt32(temp[6]);
            int day = Convert.ToInt32(temp[7]);

            //This is to populate an employees detials 
            Employee emp = new Employee
            {
                firstName = temp[0],
                lastName = temp[1],
                address = temp[2],
                postCode = temp[3],
                phoneNumber = temp[4],
                dateOfBirth = new DateTime(year, month, day)
            };

            //This class is from List, so I used the add method to add the employee.
            Add(emp);
        }
        return true;
```

and finally the form code:

```
public Salaried_Employee_Details(Employee emp)
{
    InitializeComponent();


    textBoxLastName.Text = emp.lastName;
    textBoxFirstName.Text = emp.firstName;
    textBoxAddress.Text = emp.address;
    textBoxPostCode.Text = emp.postCode;
    textBoxPhoneNumber.Text = emp.phoneNumber;
    dateTimeDateOfBirth.Text = emp.dateOfBirth.ToString();
    //textBoxSalary.Text = emp.salary;
}
```

with the work form here: 
[image: Salary form]

the format of the text file is here:

```
Smyth|Jack|London street, London City, London|01142325413|1990|3|21|37000
```

so how do I get the salaried data into the text box?

Comment: how do you actually distinguish between a normal and a salaried employee in your loaded data? because you indices don't fit quite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the split of your string into an array you either have no postal code or no number:

```
postCode = temp[3],
phoneNumber = temp[4],
```

Here are your indices of the array

```
Smyth|Jack|London street, London City, London|01142325413|1990|3|21|37000
  ^     ^                     ^                     ^       ^  ^  ^  ^
  |     |                     |                     |       |  |  |  |
  0     1                     2                     3       4  5  6  7
```

In this case 4 looks for me like a year!

If the salary is on the last position you need distinguish between a normal `Employee` and a `SalariedEmployee` In the firs case you do it like you do already and in the second case you need to create a `SalariedEmployee` object when loading your data:

```
int year = Convert.ToInt32(temp[4]);
int month = Convert.ToInt32(temp[5]);
int day = Convert.ToInt32(temp[6]);

SalariedEmployee emp = new SalariedEmployee
    {
        firstName = temp[1],
        lastName = temp[0],
        address = temp[2],
        phoneNumber = temp[3],
        dateOfBirth = new DateTime(year, month, day)
        salary = Convert.ToDecimal(temp[7]);
    };
```

EDIT: What you need to make this code work is a parameterless constructor in the `SalariedEmployee` class.

```
public SalariedEmployee()
{

}
```

or you need to use the constructor that you have written with all the parameters:

```
public SalariedEmployee(string firstName, string lastName, string
   address, string postCode, string phoneNumber, DateTime dateOfBirth,
 decimal salary)
```

which would look like this:

```
SalariedEmployee emp = new SalariedEmployee(temp[1], temp[0],temp[2],
                               "I don't know where your postcode is", 
                               temp[3],new DateTime(year, month, day),
                               Convert.ToDecimal(temp[7]));
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it is saying: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'firstName' of 'SalariedEmployee.SalariedEmployee(string, string, string, string, string, DateTime, decimal)'

Comment: `SalariedEmployee` doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @rosie You need a constructor without parameters, as David already said. I made an edit have a look

Comment: @MongZhu: Well, they don't *need* a parameterless constructor.  They could just use the constructor they already have.  Your answer is requiring one, but it's not technically necessary.

Comment: so where do I put this, I have tried but keep getting error messages?

Comment: @rosie what do you mean by "this" ? I guess in your `Load(string employeesFile)` method. You need to decide whether you hit a line with or without a salary. If you have a salary then you need to create a `SalariedEmployee` object otherwise you need to create a normal `Employee` object. both will work with your `Add` method, since they are both `Employee`

Comment: Ive put it into my load method and am still getting error, ive tried many different things to fix it

Comment: @MongZhu ive start from the star again and got this error:  A local variable or function named 'emp' is already defined in this scope

Comment: @rosie that means that you should give it a different name may be `emp_salary`

Comment: @MongZhu yes I have done this, then do this on the form...public Salaried_Employee_Details(Employee emp, Employee emp_Salary )
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBoxLastName.Text = emp.lastName;
            textBoxFirstName.Text = emp.firstName;
            textBoxAddress.Text = emp.address;
            textBoxPostCode.Text = emp.postCode;
            textBoxPhoneNumber.Text = emp.phoneNumber;
            dateTimeDateOfBirth.Text = emp.dateOfBirth.ToString();
            textBoxSalary.Text = emp_Salary.ToString();
which then comes up with the error

Comment: @MongZhu    Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'emp_Salary' of 'Salaried_Employee_Details.Salaried_Employee_Details(Employee, Employee)' on this code
 private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                Salaried_Employee_Details frm = new Salaried_Employee_Details(employees[listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex]);
                frm.Show();
            }
        }

Comment: @rosie why do you put a second parameter of type `` into the constructor of `Salaried_Employee_Details(Employee emp, Employee emp_Salary )` ?You second error comes from the point that you expect 2 parameters, but you give only one in the `buttonEdit_Click` event when creating the form. do you know how inheritance works ? you can simply cast the `Employee` to `SalariedEmployee` since `SalariedEmployee` inherits from `Employee`.

Comment: public Salaried_Employee_Details(Employee emp)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBoxLastName.Text = emp.lastName;
            textBoxFirstName.Text = emp.firstName;
            textBoxAddress.Text = emp.address;
            textBoxPostCode.Text = emp.postCode;
            textBoxPhoneNumber.Text = emp.phoneNumber;
            dateTimeDateOfBirth.Text = emp.dateOfBirth.ToString();
            textBoxSalary.Text = emp_Salary.ToString();

like that? but I then get the error emp_salary doesnt exisit in the content? @MongZh

Comment: @rosie of course it does not exist. Is the Form only for showing the data of `SalariedEmployee`? then pass an `SalariedEmployee` as parameter. then you will be able to access the `salary` property

Comment: @MongZhu  thank you, but now I am getting the error --- 
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'HRApplication.Employee' to 'HRApplication.SalariedEmployee' 
 private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                Salaried_Employee_Details frm = new Salaried_Employee_Details(employees[listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex]);
                frm.Show();
            }
        }

Comment: @rosie you really need to research more about inheritance and casting. You are using it, so you should get more information about it how it really works.Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534253/c-sharp-converting-base-class-to-child-class). Basically you need to distinguish what you might have there. try `SalariedEmployee tmp = employees[listBoxEmployees.Selecte‌​dIndex] as SalariedEmployee;` then check whether the cast has worked: `if(tmp != null)` then pass `tmp` into the constructor

Comment: @rosie will you accept my answer only if I help you to solve all of your resulting problems and write the entire programm with you ?=! ;)

Comment: No not fixed it yet :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.salary` property because the constructor is expecting an `Employee`:

```
public Salaried_Employee_Details(Employee emp)
```

Which doesn't have that property.  However, `SalariedEmployee` *does* have that property.  If the constructor needs a `SalariedEmployee` then simply change it to require one:

```
public Salaried_Employee_Details(SalariedEmployee emp)
```

Then you can use that property like any other:

```
textBoxSalary.Text = emp.salary;
```

Comment: Hi, Doing this comes up with an error on this code: private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                Salaried_Employee_Details frm = new Salaried_Employee_Details(employees[listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex]);
                frm.Show();
            }
        }   with the error been:  CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'HRApplication.Employee' to 'HRApplication.SalariedEmployee' HRApplication    any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @rosie: Well, since the constructor is expecting a `SalariedEmployee`, then you'd pass it one of those.  Not just any `Employee`.  It *looks like* this form requires a salaried employee just by the nature of the form itself, doesn't it?  It's really up to you to define what types are required for what purposes.

Comment: sorry, How do I do that, im very confused?

Comment: @rosie: The error means that you're passing it an `Employee` instead of a `SalariedEmployee`.  So I guess first you need to decide... Does this form *require* a `SalariedEmployee`?  It has a "Salary" field, so I would expect so.  But it's your design, you would be the one to decide.

Comment: ive done that like this?   public Salaried_Employee_Details(SalariedEmployee emp_Salary)
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            textBoxLastName.Text = emp_Salary.lastName; and this?  Salaried_Employee_Details frm = new Salaried_Employee_Details(SalariedEmployee[listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex]); but I stil get an error?

Comment: @rosie: That makes it *technically* require a `SalariedEmployee` object, so you would need to supply it one when calling that constructor.  You need to decide if *semantically* this form should require a salaried employee.  Basically, you have to decide what you want your program to do and how you want it to behave.  We can resolve compiler errors in a variety of ways, which one is ideal depends on what you want the program to do.

Comment: all I want it to do is display the salary as well as all the other things firstname lastname etc etc?

Comment: @rosie: Ok, well, in order to display a *salary* it needs to be a *salaried employee*, right?  The `Employee` class doesn't *have* a salary, only the `SalariedEmployee` class does.  So if the form *needs* a salaried employee, then when you create an instance of the form you need to pass it a `SalariedEmployee` object.

Comment: sorry, so how would I do that?

Comment: @rosie: It would appear from the error that `employees[]` is an array of `Employee` objects.  If you want your form to require a `SalariedEmployee` object, then you have to give it a `SalariedEmployee` object.  Not an `Employee` object.  They are two different types.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have tried doing that but always got errors

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a spot missing in the format of text file.

The string you posted

> Smyth|Jack|London street, London City,
>   London|01142325413|1990|3|21|37000

has 7 separators, which lead to an array of 8 strings, the last of them (`temp[7]`) being the salary. Instead, in your code it is assigned to the `day` property of the Employee instance.

By the way, assuming there's actually another string with the postcode formatted like this

> Smyth|Jack|London street, London City, London|L12
>   3AS|01142325413|1990|3|21|37000

you should declare emp as a SalariedEmployee class instance instead, and I recommend using the TryParse method to check whether the salary string can be converted into decimal.

```
public bool Load(string employeesFile)
    {
        bool isLoaded = false;
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("employees.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Splitting the data using |
                string[] temp = line.Split('|');

                int year = Convert.ToInt32(temp[5]);
                int month = Convert.ToInt32(temp[6]);
                int day = Convert.ToInt32(temp[7]);

                //Populating the employees details 

                decimal _salary;
                if (Decimal.TryParse(temp[8], out _salary))
                {
                    SalariedEmployee emp = new SalariedEmployee(firstName: temp[1],
                        lastName: temp[0],
                        address: temp[2],
                        postCode: temp[3],
                        phoneNumber: temp[4],
                        dateOfBirth: new DateTime(year, month, day),
                        salary: _salary)
```

at this point, you need to also be sure the List parameter is changed to be of SalariedEmployee type, otherwise you'll get a compiler error in the following line

```
                Add(emp);
                isLoaded = true;
                }
            }
            return isLoaded;
        }
```

at this point, in the form you just need to change the type argument and un-check the last line of code

```
public Salaried_Employee_Details(SalariedEmployee emp)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBoxLastName.Text = emp.lastName;
    textBoxFirstName.Text = emp.firstName;
    textBoxAddress.Text = emp.address;
    textBoxPostCode.Text = emp.postCode;
    textBoxPhoneNumber.Text = emp.phoneNumber;
    dateTimeDateOfBirth.Text = emp.dateOfBirth.ToString();
    textBoxSalary.Text = emp.salary;
}
```

Hope this might help you.

Bye!
Davide.

Comment: the `TryParse` will break when you run into an `IndexOutOfRangeException` in this line: `Decimal.TryParse(temp[8], ...`.

Comment: @MongZhu I assumed temp[8] is where the salary data is, adding the postcode in the source string.