# Short hand to copy properties from parent to child

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, casting, copy

I have the following class tructure:

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public int Property1;
        public int Property2;
        public int Property3;
        //Lots more properties
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public int Property80;
    }
```

and a list of parent like this:

```
var parentList = new List<Parent>
        {
            //Some data....
        };
```

I now want to make a new list of child that has all the data from `parentList`

I know I can do this:

```
var childList = parentList.Select(x => new Child { Property1 = x.Property1, Property2 = x.Property2, //etc }
```

but my question is, is there a shorthand or one line way of doing this, to save me having to write a huge list of properties out?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534253/c-sharp-converting-base-class-to-child-class/25653977, also consider using object-to-object mapping library such as AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `Parent` list use `Child` class

```
var parentList = new List<Parent>
{
    new Child { Property1 = 1, Property2 = 2, Property3 = 3 },
    new Child { Property1 = 4, Property2 = 5, Property3 = 6 },
    new Child { Property1 = 7, Property2 = 8, Property3 = 9 }
};
```

This is the equivalent of `Parent p = new Child { Property1 = 1, Property2 = 2, Property3 = 3 }`

Now you can cast it to `Child` and just add the missing properties in `Select`

```
var childList1 = parentList.Select(x => { Child y = (Child)x; y.Property80 = 80; return y; });
```