# Convert current type to its inherited type

Tags: c#, interface, type-conversion

I have a treeview which is made up of `IDetail` and `IAssembly` items.

```
public interface IDetail {
    string Nomenclature { get; set; }
    string Cost { get; set; }
}
public interface IAssembly:IDetail{
    IEnumerable<IDetail> DirectChildren { get; }
    IEnumerable<IDetail> LoadChildren();
}
```

I'm adding the ability to insert childen into the tree. I can add a `IDetail` child to the `IAssembly` just fine but want to include ability to add a child to the `IDetail`. This means I need to convert `IDetail` to `IAssembly` so that it can have children.

How do I cast `IDetail` to `IAssembly` assuming I'm working within `IDetail`. Can I cast the `object` I'm in to `IAssembly`? `this` is only a `get` and I can't set `this=(IAssembly)this;`

Thanks for reading,

**UPDATE**
Let me clarify my question a bit.. I don't want to add children to `IDetail` but if a user decides to branch out the current item more, then the current item of type `IDetail` will switch to `IAssembly`, then add `IDetail` as a child.

Comment: Well you can't *assign* to `this` - but you can still *cast* `this`, assuming you're confident that it really is an `IAssembly`. It's hard to know the exact context here, given that you're not going to be writing implementation code in an interface anyway...

Comment: Would it make sense to move `DirectChildren` and `LoadChildren()` declarations to `IDetail`?

Comment: I believe this post may have your answer.  I think it's deliberately not able to be done.  I realize you're dealing with interfaces, but still a class that implements the IDetail interface shouldn't be able to be cast backwards like that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329470/convert-derived-class-to-base-class

Comment: If you are making `IDetail` aware of children, you don't need two interfaces.

Comment: It's not that I want to make IDetail aware of children, but before I add a child I want to change the type to IAssembly, then add children

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to Covariance and ContraVariance (or CounterVariance) on MSDN [This is the article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

If the object you put inside the DirectChildren is an IDetail you cannot convert it to IAssembly, but if the object you put in the DirectChildren is an IAssembly you can use its method making a cast of the Directchildren element to IAssembly to use its method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add children to both `IDetail` types and `IAssembly` types you can try moving the child related code (field(s) and method(s)) up into `IDetail` rather than `IAssembly`.

**Update:**
Rather than casting the same object to a new type, you should be able to simply create a new `IAssembly` object and add the current `IDetail` object as a child. You would then have to replace the `IDetail` object in the treeview with the new `IAssembly` object.

Comment: I don't want Detail to have Children but want to change Detail to Assembly then add children

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
   {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Program P = new Program(); //Creating an instance.
            IAssembly iAssebly = ((IAssembly)P); //Casting it to IAssembly.
            IDetail iDetail = ((IDetail)P); //Casting it to IDetail.

            IAssembly iDetailToIAssembly = ((IAssembly)iDetail); //Casting IDetail to IAssemmbly.
            IDetail iAssemblyToIDetail = ((IDetail)iAssebly); //Casting IAssemmbly to IDetail.
        }

    }
```

Comment: so with this example it would be how to cast Program to something else while inside of itself

Comment: Correct. Remember you cant make a child inherit from a base class. cause it is a specialization of the base class.

Comment: Sorry If i miss understood the question. My English terms are a bit lacking.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Composite Pattern,` it's gof structural pattern, you can find code sample, copy paste, documentation  and class diagram.

link : http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern

Comment: With this example I would need to add IAssembly(composite) to the tree  before I could add IDetail (leafs) to it. Which will probably have to do for now. What I would prefer is to only always add IDetails and whenever an IDetail gets something added to it, it converts itself to IAssembly then adds child.

Comment: yes i inderstand, but with your organization you can define your composite and your child, these two respect contract