# Check if the instance is type of base class or derived class after keyword 'as'?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Please look at the following code:

```
// Base class
public abstract class Aircraft
{
    public virtual void Fly()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Aircraft flies");
    }
}

// Derived class
public class Plane : Aircraft
{
    public new void Fly()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plane flies");
    }
}

// Execution
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lPlane = new Plane();
        Console.WriteLine(lPlane.GetType()); // Plane
        lPlane.Fly(); // Plane flies

        var lAircraft = lPlane as Aircraft;
        Console.WriteLine(lAircraft.GetType()); // Plane
        lAircraft.Fly(); // Aircraft flies
    }
}
```

The following line casts the `Plane` to an `Aircaft`:

```
var lAircraft = lPlane as Aircraft;
```

So I would expected, that `lAircraft` is type of `Aircraft` now. But it isn´t. It is of type `Plane`:

```
Console.WriteLine(lAircraft.GetType()); // Plane
```

How can I check if the current instance is type of base class or derived class after cast by the keyword `as`?

Comment: You can't change the runtime type of an object; casting only changes the compile time type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
var lAircraft = lPlane as Aircraft;
```

Will be compiled to this:

```
Aircraft aircraft = lPlane;
```

So that means the `as` keyword here do nothing because you can't convert your derived class to it's base class. To find out more you can read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8329517/2946329

Comment: lAircraft.Fly(); // Aircraft flies

Comment: @Simon You've created a new instance of `Aircraft` so yes, it indeed will print the Aircraft flies, but the type of `lPlane` is still plane since as I said already you can not convert it to it's base class.